# C++: the function collapses at the 4th element of the array

Tags: c++

Could you have a look at what I've faced: http://sdrv.ms/WgafvN

And another screenshot: http://sdrv.ms/UZIp6H

The text of my function is:

```
bool print_all_points(POINT** pointer)
{

    if (pointer == NULL||is_array_empty(pointer)) 
    {
        cout << "The array of points is empty." << endl << endl;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        int n = _msize(pointer)/sizeof(pointer[0]);
        cout << "The list of points: " << endl<< endl;
        cout << "id (x, y)" << endl;
        cout << "----------" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << (*pointer[i]).id << " (" << (*pointer[i]).x << ", " << (*pointer[i]).y << ")" << endl;      
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This function is expected to print out all the points in an array. My problem is that it perfectly prints the array of 3 points rather than that of 4 points. At the 4th point it bites the dust.

I can't catch what the trouble is.
From the picture it is visible that:
1. All 4 elements of the array are present.
2. It is correctly determined that there 4 of them.

What is the problem?
Could you give me a kick here?

ADDED LATER.

The function which calls this:

```
POINT**  new_point(POINT** pointer, int occup)
{
    char x;
    char y;
    system("cls");
    cout << "INPUT A NEW POINT" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Input x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Input y: ";
    cin >> y;
    size_t m;
    if (pointer != NULL)
    {
        m = _msize(pointer);
    }

    POINT * tmp_point = new POINT();
    (*tmp_point).id = occup;
    (*tmp_point).x = x-48;
    (*tmp_point).y = y-48;  

    POINT** pn = new POINT * [occup];
    int necessary_memory = occup * 4; // ???? 4 is the size of a pointer.
    if (occup !=1)
    {
        memcpy(pn, pointer, necessary_memory);      
    }
    POINT ** tmp = new POINT * [occup];
    pn[occup - 1] = tmp_point;
    memcpy(tmp, pn, occup * sizeof(POINT)); 
    delete[] pn;
    pn = tmp;   
    size_t n = _msize(pn);
    cout << endl;
    print_all_points(pn);
    return pn;
}
```

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I was wondering the same thing, I checked, it seems like `_msize` is a non standard function of M$VS used to get size of dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: @Joachim pointer is an array of pointers. it represents a dynamic array which I resize in another procedure, which calls this very function. _msize determines how much memory we have allocated. By dividing this figure by the size of element we wll determine. Well, I believe that I have determined the size of array correctly.

Comment: well, I use Visual Studio 2010. _msize is documented. Is it something wrong with it? Then I'll just use a counter or something.

Comment: And you have allocated the memory for `pointer` with `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` as per the [`_msize` manual page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2s077bc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Consider using `std::vector<POINT>`.

Comment: POINT** pn = new POINT * [occup];print_all_points(pn); Well, occup is 4 here, this is my counter.

Comment: @lucasmrod, thank you for your desire to help. but I can't. This is well ahead of what I have read in the book. I am studying the very beginning - procegural programming. Well, no, I'll have to adhere to the new operator.

Comment: lucasmod has a very valid point. In C++ there are _very_ few reasons to use raw arrays or pointers. Using the [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and its [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) will make your life as a C++ programmer so much easier.

Comment: Could it be, that you allocated more memory than you're actual using? Consider using `std::array.size()` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: My guess is that you are not allocating any memory for each POINT element, so your array is just an array of uninitialised pointers.

Comment: well, I added the text of the calling function. Not a very good idea to post it here but pardon me for that. occup is 4. so, we allocate 16 bytes for the array of pointers (4 bytes for each pointer). Well, I can't see any fault here.

Comment: well if you're on 64-bit architecture, then @PaulR is right.

Comment: yes, 64-bit. What can be done? And how to understand this phenomenon?

Comment: An experienced physicist can write FORTRAN programs in any language. Jokes aside, **NEVER EVER** use _msize and operator new[] together, E-V-E-R. You will be bitten (you already are). operator new is **not** malloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

several problems:

- not copying enough data in 64-bit

  ```
  int necessary_memory = occup * 4;
  ```

  should be

  ```
  int necessary_memory = occup * sizeof(POINT*);
  ```
- copying too much data

  ```
  memcpy(tmp, pn, occup * sizeof(POINT));
  ```

  should be:

  ```
  memcpy(tmp, pn, occup * sizeof(POINT*));
  ```
- Someone else can chime in, but I am not sure _msize should be used on memory allocated by new.  Is that right?   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2s077bc(v=vs.80).aspx
- *fucntion* in the title should be *function*

You're welcome.  You owe me a beer.

Oh yea, I found my shoes... where would you like it?

Comment: A marvellous kick. Thank you very much. Beer from me.